# how to install TSC TA210 barcode printer driver in linux

Tags: linux, barcode-printing

Request you kindly to please help me in installing TSC TA210 Barcode Printer in LINUX environment. I have installed Linuxfx in my system. I tried downloading windows .exe from the TSC website and tried to run it using WINE, but of no use. Even though TSC has provided the drivers in LINUX, I am not able to install it in my LINUXFX. Please help!

Comment: `I am not able to install it in my LINUXFX` What do you mean "not able"? Please show what have you tried, how did it fail? Why write here - write to the vendor - tscprinters - and ask him for help?

Comment: @KamilCuk hi, thanks for your suggestion, will do as suggested!

Answer (score 0):

As @KamilCuk suggested, visited the TSC website and downloaded the appropriate drivers from the below link and installed the drivers successfully in my LINUX OS!

https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/support/Support_Download/TA210_Series